# Why FireFox remote web driver is headless on a windows machine?

Tags: firefox, selenium, remotewebdriver

I am running selenium grid and both server and nodes are win server 2008 (I also tried running nodes on Win 7 in case it matters). Tests run fine except that when I remote desktop to my nodes I cannot see any Firefox window. I can see the Firefox process running in task manger but I cannot see the window itself. It seems like they are running as a headless browser. Is there any way to avoid that so I can see tests running?

I am using .net library with FF26.0 and Selenium Server 2.39.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade FF to 25.0 version